# replace text based on another column value

Tags: mysql

First time post and was looking for a little bit of help, I'd be very grateful if you could advise me,

I have a table on my server, eg:-

Column A    Column B
    Column C
1
    30-08-2015 hello
    42
3
    30-08-2015 hello
    45
2
    30-08-2015 hello
    20
4
    30-08-2015 hello
    1
1
    30-08-2015 hello
    32
1
    30-08-2015 hello
    21
2
    30-08-2015 hello
    21
3
    30-08-2015 hello
    0
4
    30-08-2015 hello
    21
1
    30-08-2015 hello
    24
1
    30-08-2015 hello
    67

I am looking for a command that would change column B to 30-08-2015 bye but only when column A = 1

I've found a few replace statements but that doesnt take into account the value of Column A. Any advice??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at the [MySQL UPDATE command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html). It would allow you to do something like

```
UPDATE table 
SET B='30-08-2015 bye' 
WHERE A=1;
```